# Asp .NET MVC dropdownlist cascading retrieve value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I work with Asp.Net MVC4 in my form I have dropdownlist in cascading, when I select "Distrito" in another DropDownList loads the values for "Sucursal" this works correctly I can insert a record my problem is when I need to search for an item to retrieve data not setting the correct value.
This is the code in the controller:

```
public JsonResult Buscar(string id){
        string Mensaje = "";
        Models.cSinDenuncias oDenuncia = new Models.cSinDenuncias();
        oDenuncia.sd_iddenuncia = id;
        var denuncia = Servicio.RecuperaDenuncia<Models.cSinDenuncias>(ref Mensaje, oDenuncia.getPk(), oDenuncia);
        string HoraDenuncia = denuncia.sd_horadenuncia.ToString();
        return Json(new {objDenuncia = denuncia, hDenuncia = HoraDenuncia});
    }
```

in objDenuncia I have the values for example the value objDenuncia.sd_pardistrito = "TJA" objDenuncia.sd_sucursal = "YCB"

When I do find this is my code in the view:

```
function Buscar() {
        var Iddenuncia = $('#sd_iddenuncia').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Buscar", "raDenuncia")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { Id: Iddenuncia },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {                    
                $('#sd_iddenuncia').val(data.objDenuncia.sd_iddenuncia);
                $('#ddlParDistrito').val(data.objDenuncia.sd_pardistrito);
                $('#ddlParDistrito').trigger('change');
                $('#ddlSucursal').trigger('change');
                $('#ddlSucursal').val();                    
                $('#ddlSucursal').val(data.objDenuncia.sd_sucursal);                    
                $("select#ddlSucursal").val(data.objDenuncia.sd_sucursal);                  
            }
        });
    }
```

The value in the dropdownlist ddlParDistrito is "TJA" text is "TARIJA" shows me well the text in the component the execute $('#ddlParDistrito').trigger('change'); this load data for dropdownlist "Sucursal" but not set the current value, this showme "-- SUCURSAL --" here the current value should be "YCB" with text "YACUIBA" please help me with this problem.

Regards
Ricardo

In my view I hae this dropdownlist, for "SUCURSAL" I use new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty()

```
 <td class="name"><label>Distrito:</label></td>
 <td class="name">@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.sd_pardistrito, new SelectList(ViewBag.Distrito as System.Collections.IEnumerable, "cp_idparametro", "cp_descparametro"), "-- DISTRITO --", new { id = "ddlParDistrito", style = "width:125px;" })</td>
 <td class="name"><label>Sucursal:</label></td>
 <td class="name">@Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.sd_sucursal, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>(), "cp_idparametro", "cp_descparametro"), "-- SUCURSAL --", new { id = "ddlSucursal", style = "width:125px;" })</td>
```

An in my controller I use this method for load the dropdownlist when change option in "DISTRITO"

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
    public JsonResult LoadSucusalByDistrito(string id)
    {
        var sucursalList = this.GetSucursal(id);
        var sucursalData = sucursalList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.cp_descparametro,
            Value = m.cp_idparametro,
        });
        return Json(sucursalData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In my view, when change option ddlDistrito load ddlSucursal

```
$("#ddlParDistrito").change(function () {
            var idDistrito = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/raDenuncia/LoadSucusalByDistrito", { id: idDistrito },
                function (distritoData) {
                    var select = $("#ddlSucursal");
                    select.empty();
                    select.append($('<option/>', {
                        value: 0,
                        text: "-- SUCURSAL --"
                    }));
                    $.each(distritoData, function (index, itemData) {
                        select.append($('<option/>', {
                            value: itemData.Value,
                            text: itemData.Text
                        }));
                    });
                });
        });
```

Comment: How are you loading the values into ddlSucursal? Is there an event handler for ddlParDistrito which loads the values into ddlSucursal when ddlParDistrito's values change? If so, did you check if ddlSucursal is populated with proper values before calling `$('#ddlSucursal').val(data.objDenuncia.sd_sucursal);`?

Comment: If the data are filled in dropdownlist "ddlSucurcal" by clicking on the component I can see loaded data to see the source code of the page the select has no data but to see in web page to give click on the dropdownlist are data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your statement clearly in the comment reply below the question.

I will try to explain what I think maybe the issue and you can let me know if I am onto something, when the statement `$('#ddlSucursal').val(data.objDenuncia.sd_sucursal);` is executed I think the drop down `ddlSucursal` does not have data. Is there a way for you to move that statement inside the `$("#ddlParDistrito").change...` function, so that it executes after you have finished.

So in effect if you can try the following:

```
var currentSucursal = null;
function Buscar() {
    var Iddenuncia = $('#sd_iddenuncia').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Buscar", "raDenuncia")',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { Id: Iddenuncia },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {                    
            $('#sd_iddenuncia').val(data.objDenuncia.sd_iddenuncia);
            $('#ddlParDistrito').val(data.objDenuncia.sd_pardistrito);

            // Set the global variable to the currently given sucursal value
            currentSucursal = data.objDenuncia.sd_sucursal;

            // Call the change event after the global values is set
            $('#ddlParDistrito').trigger('change');
            // $('#ddlSucursal').trigger('change');
        }
    });
}
```

and then

```
$("#ddlParDistrito").change(function () {
    var idDistrito = $(this).val();
    $.getJSON("/raDenuncia/LoadSucusalByDistrito", { id: idDistrito },
        function (distritoData) {
            var select = $("#ddlSucursal");
            select.empty();
            select.append($('<option/>', {
                value: 0,
                text: "-- SUCURSAL --"
            }));
            $.each(distritoData, function (index, itemData) {
                select.append($('<option/>', {
                    value: itemData.Value,
                    text: itemData.Text
                }));
            });

            // Check if the global variable has value
            if(null!==currentSucursal) {
                $('#ddlSucursal').val(currentSucursal);
            }
        });
});
```

I hope my inline comments are self explanatory.